# Bootstrap multi select not expanding on mouse click

Tags: php, codeigniter

Inspection code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="Relatedcategory_name" title="Nothing selected">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Nothing selected</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
</button>

<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
    <label>Related Category</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
    <select multiple class="form-control selectpicker"  id="Relatedcategory_name" name="Relatedcategory_name[]">
        <option value="0">...Select Category...</option>
        <?php 
        if (isset($category_links)) {
            foreach ($category_links as $rs) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rs->Category_Id; ?>"><?php echo $rs->Category_Name ?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Nothing is shown in inspect and it works when reached at tab or some key press.

Comment: are you trying to say when you hit any key before the ui is updated ?

Comment: it is solved actually when we click dropdown it was not working but when some key was pressed alongside then it was coming down. solved by removing multiple calls to bootstrap files in multiple headers.

Comment: Oh cool ✌, can you answer it , so others can see the solution

Comment: everything was fine in the code but multiple bootstrap calls were clashing i mentioned it in the comment